# display a visio vsd file in a picturebox in c#

Tags: c#, picturebox, visio

I have an visio file and I want to display this in a picturebox. Furthermore I want to manipulate the color of a certain shape from this file when a button is clicked.

something like:

```
this.pictureBox.Image = global::Foo.Properties.Resources.visioImage;
```

will not work. 
So how do I include a vsd file in the pictureBox as an Image, without losing the ability to change the color of a shape?